# Trying to separate four items with comma in Dropdown list

Tags: jquery, ajax

Trying to separate four items with comma which is bind in  item from database on success of jQuery Ajax.
html side

```
<td><select class='form-control' id='Certific'><option value='' disabled='disabled' selected='selected'>Please select a name</option></select></td>
```

on success of jQuery Ajax function I am appending it option like this way.

```
success: function (r) {
    var Certific = $("[id*=Certific]");
    $.each(r.d, function () {
        Certific.append($("<option></option>").val(this['CODE_VALUE']).html([this['CODE_VALUE'], this['CODE_DESC'], this['CODE_SUB_VALUE'], this['CODE_SUB_DESC']]));
    });
}
```

o/p is appearing like this

[image]

I want to arrange dropdown like :127,Coil,wt,1KGS and remove second dropdown item "Please select a name".

Comment: If the answer helps in resolving your query, please mark it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

For the first part simply remove the value "Please select a name" from the select tag.

```
<select class='form-control' id='Certific'><option value='' disabled='disabled' selected='selected'></option></select>
```

For adding comma you can try the following. (Code is not tested)

```
success: function (r) {
var Certific = $("[id*=Certific]");
var option = $('<option/>');

$.each(r.d, function () {
    var value= this['CODE_VALUE'] +', ' + this['CODE_DESC'] +', ' + this['CODE_SUB_VALUE'] +', ' + this['CODE_SUB_DESC'];
    option.attr({ 'value': this['CODE_VALUE'] }).text(value);
    $(option).append(option);
});
$(Certific).append(option);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change tour first option like that:

```
<option value="" disabled selected>Select your option</option>
```